# Getting 500 error while calling REST webservice from Stored Procedure with SQL CLR

Tags: c#, rest, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I use a SQL-CLR procedure (created a dll and used it as an assembly) in a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) to pass an xml to a rest web service. I am always getting an error 500 - is something wrong with the way I am passing the string?

I am sure its getting authenticated since I am getting an error if I give the wrong userid and password. Can someone help?

This is the SQL-CLR procedure and below is how I call from the stored procedure:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public partial class StoredProcCM
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void SampleWSPost(SqlString weburl, String xmlIn, out SqlString returnval)
    {
        string url = Convert.ToString(weburl);
        string feedData = string.Empty;
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            Stream stream = null;
            StreamReader streamReader = null;

            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(xmlIn);
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
            mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));   
            webrequest.Credentials = mycache;

            // set method as post
            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            // set content type
            webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // set content length
            webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            // get stream data out of webrequest object
            Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            // declare & read response from service

            //------------------------
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            feedData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            streamReader.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        returnval = feedData;
    }
};
```

I create a dll using csc and use this dll in the stored procedure as follows: `@XmlString` has the xml

```
SET @webUrl = 'https://test.abc.com:501/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?channel=:CHANNEL1:TEST_SOAP_Sender'

exec @res= SampleWSPost @webUrl,@XmlString,@res
```

Comment: The webservice I was consuming required a SOAP wrapper around the xml, even though its RESTful. I added the part and it worked just fine.

Comment: REST can use SOAP as underlying protocol, not just HTTP...